# Class C from assembly A1 implements interface from assembly A2. When using C, need to reference both A1 and A2

Tags: .net, architecture, dependencies

This is by design, according to the answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810104/use-types-referenced-by-a-referenced-project-in-c)

But I really don't want to reference both assemblies, it feels like I'm breaking encapsulation (the users of A1 shouldn't know that A1 uses A2 for its implementation...)

I thought of moving the interface definition to another assembly, let's call it "Core", and have both A2 and A1's client reference it. This feels cleaner to me.

My question is: Is this good design? Or is there a standard .NET solution to this that I'm not aware of? On the other hand, I worry that "Core" will end up being a nasty mix of totally unrelated interfaces... What do you think?

Comment: How does this "break encapsulation"?

Comment: Perhaps my choice of words was wrong. Imagine that the interface which C implements is not used by C's clients (in C++, this would be done with private inheritance, IIRC). I want to hide that implementation detail

Comment: Essentially the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466069/how-to-re-export-types-from-a-referenced-net-assembly) here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it to my satisfaction, please tell me what you think:

(Warning: this is IDE-specific, don't know if I could pull it off in, say, SharpDevelop)

1. In A1, instead of referencing the A2 assembly, in Visual Studio, right-click the A1 project and select "Add Existing Item". Select the interface file. **Before pressing the Add Button**, notice it's a dropdown button: drop it and select "Add as Link". If you don't do it this way, you'll have to mantain multiple copies of the interface, which is a hassle
2. Remove the reference from A1 to A2 (if all you used from it was the interface)
3. Voila! A1's clients only need a reference to A1. I think this is because now the interface is a type which is defined in both the A1 and A2 assemblies. I don't think that endangers manteinance, because the interface is still defined in only one source code file. Ok, its's compiled into two assemblies, so it's a sort of "binary duplication", but I don't think that's bad... Do you?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this doesn't break encapsulation.

Encapsulation means that the implementation details are not relevant - so long as you program to the interface, encapsulation is intact.

Secondly - if you want to use both the interface and implementation, you need to reference the assemblies both are in (disregarding plug-in architectures). How else would your code work? If there is no reference to the implementation, you can't instantiate a concrete type. If there is no reference to the interface, you can't use it in your code.

Comment: About the second point: I'm mostly a C++ guy. So I write my interfaces in .h files, #include them where necessary and everything adds up. These interfaces don't belong to a particular project (when using them across projects), which feels more natural to me. Is there a way of doing things like this in C#?

Comment: @dario_ramos - Not really. You _could_ have all the interfaces in one assembly and implementations in another. But this is hardly the same as header files.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not have private inheritance. If class A1 implements interface A2, then that is public information, which is exposed to users of class A1, exactly as though A2 were a base class and not an interface.

Yes, you must reference both assemblies.